# How to type to a password properly in plink using C# after login in the server

Tags: c#, linux, putty, plink

I'm using C# and Plink to automate our process in putty, so I'm having a problem when I'm using the "WriteLine("PASSWORD");" and typing my password in it, the server response is password not valid/or the wrong password, so since when typing a password in Linux it is not showing (based on "StandardOutput"), I'm not sure if the password is really being input by the WriteLine function Correctly.

I tried already executing the Plink directly in C# using "Process" and I also used CMD to execute plink but I'm having the same problem. I also used the pipe method but still no success

I tried this code but no success

```
// access to the server
strw.WriteLine("swrap user@SERVER2313");

// execute a java program to upload file in database
strw.WriteLine("JAVA PROG");

// will return where in you will type username and password of the database
Enter DB username: 
strw.WriteLine("Username"); // for username 

Enter DB password:
strw.WriteLine("PASSWORD");// for password
```

I also tried this code

```
strw.WriteLine("echo JAVA PROG | username | password");
```

Comment: The issue is the return character which is different in windows from linux.  Do not use WriteLine instead strw.Write("PASSWORD" + '\r');

Comment: jdweng is right. Though in the first place, you should not run an external application to implement SSH. Use SSH library for .NET instead.

Comment: Thank you for responding jdweng and MartinPrikryl i will try your suggestion now :)

Comment: Hi Team, i for got to respond into this, concatenating "/n" works for me.
strw.Write("PASSWORD" + "\n");